# Place custom view on Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar

I want to display Image,Title name,and two left right buttons. That I have done successfully.
Here is the code:

```
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];

    UIButton *leftButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    [leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previous-arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goPrevious:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [leftButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 14, 13)];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Title.png"]];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(leftButton.frame.origin.x+leftButton.frame.size.width+4, 20, 50, 50)];

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x+imageView.frame.size.width+4, 30, 100, 40)];
    NSString *cName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

    [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [nameLabel setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    [nameLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
     CGSize expectedLabelSize = [cName sizeWithFont:nameLabel.font 
                                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(100, 40) 
                                            lineBreakMode:nameLabel.lineBreakMode]; 
    [nameLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(imageView.frame.origin.x+imageView.frame.size.width+4, 35, expectedLabelSize.width, expectedLabelSize.height)];
    nameLabel.text=cName;

    UIButton *rightButton = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"next-arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton setFrame:CGRectMake(nameLabel.frame.origin.x+nameLabel.frame.size.width+4, 50, 14, 13)];
    [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(next:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [view addSubview:nameLabel];
    [view addSubview:imageView];
    [view addSubview:leftButton];
    [view addSubview:rightButton];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = view;
```

This code is written in cellForRowAtIndexPath. The view is showing properly on navigation bar but after scrolling the tableview. Initially it is displaying on wrong coordinates.

Please Suggest.

Comment: Have you tried making the x-coordinate of the custom view not dependent on the left button, e.g. 20? Does it work then? (apart from it not changing to the button width of course) And why in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Data need to display in navigationbar is gathering from array and depends on Tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. It's not meant to be in tableView protocol!

Comment: That was a thing I noticed too, may indeed help because maybe when the table is still initialising it doesn't handle subviews nicely or something :)

Comment: When cell is initialized ("to be displayed") it doesn't know all details about it's surrounding views, especially sizes of them. That's the problem.

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah, that could turn out to be not so nice if it's put in a view :)